# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket - Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

I was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGolbRsvgnA) about making a chat App that can run on pc and android using kivy and sockets.

I connected to the server with a username and tried to send a message and I got this error

```
  File "c:\Users\adebu\Documents\Andriod chat app\webchat.kv", line 82, in <module>
     on_press: root.send_message()
  File "c:\Users\adebu\Documents\Andriod chat app\main.py", line 20, in send_message
     client.send(cmessage.encode("utf-8"))
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"
```

I have tried to rewrite the script multiple times and I have compared it with other socket scripts I have made in the past but can not find the answer to this problem

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import socket
import threading

kivy.require("1.9.0")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

class MyRoot(BoxLayout):

    
    def __int__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()

    def send_message(self):      
        cmessage = (f"{self.nickname_text.text}: {self.message_text.text}")
        client.send(cmessage.encode("utf-8"))
    
        
    def connect_to_server(self):
        if self.nickname_text != "":
            client.connect((self.ip_text.text, 9999))
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if message == 'NICK':
                client.send(self.nickname_text.text.encode('utf-8'))
                self.send_btn.disable = True
                self.message_text.disable = True
                self.connect_btn.disable = True
                self.ip_text.disable = True

                self.make_invisible(self.connection_grid)
                self.make_invisible(self.connect_btn)

                thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
                thread.start()

    def make_invisible(self, widget):
        widget.visible = False
        widget.size_hint_x = None
        widget.size_hint_y = None
        widget.height = 0
        widget.width = 0
        widget.txt = ""
        widget.opacity = 0

    def receive(self):
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            try:
                message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                self.chat_text.text += message + "\n"
            except:
                print("ERROR")
                client.close()
                stop = True

class WebChat(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()

webChat = WebChat()
webChat.run()
```

this is the kivy file:

```
<MyRoot>

    ip_text: ip_text
    nickname_text: nickname_text
    connect_btn: connect_btn
    chat_text: chat_text
    message_text: message_text
    send_btn: send_btn
    connection_grid: connection_grid

    orientation: 'vertical'


    GridLayout:
        id: connection_grid
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        height: 125
        size_hint: (1, None)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Server IP"
                font_size: 42
                color: 180, 100, 50, 1
            TextInput:
                id: ip_text
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 50
                font_size: 36
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Nickname"
                font_size: 42
                color: 180, 100, 50, 1
            TextInput:
                id: nickname_text
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 50
                font_size: 36
    Button:
        id:connect_btn
        text: "Connect"
        font_size: 32
        size: 100, 50
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: 70
        on_press: root.connect_to_server()
        color: 180, 100, 50, 1
    Label:
        text: "Chat History"
        font_size: 42
        height: 50
        size_hint: (1, None)
        color: 23, 0, 0, 1
    TextInput:
        id: chat_text
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: 450
        multiline: True
        font_size: 36
        readonly: True
        disabled: True
    Label:
        text: "Your Message"
        font_size: 42
        height: 50
        size_hint: (1, None)
        color: 23, 0, 0, 1
    TextInput:
        id: message_text
        font_size: 36
        disabled: True
    Button:
        id: send_btn
        text: "Send"
        font_size: 32
        size: 100, 50
        on_press: root.send_message()
        disabled: True
```

this is the server:

```py
import socket
import threading
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []


def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)


def handle_connection(client):
    stop = False
    while not stop:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = client.index(client)
            client.remove(client)
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            broadcast(f"{nickname} left the chat!".encode('utf-8'))
            stop = True


def main():
    print("server is online...")
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected to {addr}")
        
        client.send("NICK".encode('utf-8'))

        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        print(f"Nickname is {nickname}")

        broadcast(f"{nickname} joined the chat!".encode('utf-8'))

        client.send("You are now connected!".encode('utf-8'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_connection, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: FYI: Any `sockets` example that treats TCP as a message-based protocol is not a tutorial you should follow.

Comment: *"main.py", line 19"* - the line number from the error and the shown statement do not match the line numbers from the code you show in your question. Please provide the error by the exact code shown.

Comment: Sorry Steffen the appropriate error code is now in the description